# Update manager always wants to reboot

Tags: update-manager, reboot, prompt

I have the recent Ubuntu 14.04 version installed. Since a few days the update manager keeps asking me to reboot. Even if I do reboot and no new updates are installed, it asks again after startup. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Run `ls /var/run/reboot-required`, to check if it exists. If there, try removing it.

Comment: mikewhatever, thanks! Removing this file did it.

Comment: This is useful also when one knows very well that the updates do not really require any reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to press the "check" button in the Update Manager.  Sometimes the information it is working with is out of date.

Comment: There is no "check" buttons. Only "Reboot now", "Reboot later" and "Settings". I clicked settings, unchecked a random source, checked it again and saved with reloading the buffer. No new updates to install, but still the reboot prompt again.